# Spring REST PagingAndSortingRepository wont display 'nex't & 'previous' links

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am trying to implement PagingAndSortingRepository from spring boot data REST.

It certainly does return a paged response, however i cant find a way to get it to display navigation links between pages. I have looked at quite a few tutorials and documentation on this, and it seems that it should just happen as a consequence of using the PagingAndSortingRepository that is provided.

Please advise me someone! it should be so simple.
Thanks in advance.

Classes:

```
@RestController
public class CommentController {

private final CommentFacade facade;

@Autowired
public CommentController(CommentRepository commentdao) {

    this.facade = new CommentFacadeImpl(commentdao);
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/comments", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public PagedResources<Resource<Comment>> getPagedList(@RequestParam(value = "user-id", required = true) Long userId) {

    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(1, 10);

    Page<Comment> commentsList =  facade.findAll(pageable);

    List<Resource<Comment>> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Comment comment : commentsList) {

        Resource<Comment> commentResource = new Resource<>(comment);

        commentResource.add(linkTo(methodOn(CommentController.class)
                .getSpecificComment(comment.getId())).withSelfRel());

        resourceList.add(commentResource);
    }

    PagedResources<Resource<Comment>> resources = new PagedResources<>(resourceList,
            new PageMetadata(commentsList.getNumber(), commentsList.getTotalElements(), commentsList.getTotalPages(), 5),
            linkTo(methodOn(CommentController.class)
                    .getPagedList(userId)).withSelfRel());

    return resources;
}
```

}

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CommentRepository extends     PagingAndSortingRepository<Comment, Long> {

Page findAll(Pageable pageRequest);
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name="comment")
@EnableEntityLinks
@RepositoryRestResource
public class Comment  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private @JsonIgnore Long id;

@Column(name="created")
private Date created;

@Column(name="latitude")
private @JsonIgnore Float latitude;

@Column(name="longitude")
private @JsonIgnore Float longitude;

@Column(name="ip")
private @JsonIgnore String ip;

@Column(name="text")
private String comment;


@Column(name="sender_id")
private Long senderId;

@JsonIgnore
private Long postId;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name="deleted")
private Boolean deleted;

protected Comment() {};

public Comment(String comment, Long senderId, Long post_id) {
    this.id = null;
    this.created = new Date();
    this.latitude = 12.1111111138563456f;
    this.longitude = -17.444333333333f;
    this.ip = "34.6.5.213";
    this.comment = "some comment";
    this.senderId = 1L;
    this.postId = post_id;
    this.deleted = false;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}

public Float getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Float latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Float getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Float longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getIp() {
    return ip;
}

public void setIp(String ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public Long getSenderId() {
    return senderId;
}

public void setSenderId(Long senderId) {
    this.senderId = senderId;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
@JoinTable(name = "post")
public Long getPostId() {
    return postId;
}

public void setPostId(Long postId) {
    this.postId = postId;
}

public Boolean getDeleted() {
    return deleted;
}

public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
    this.deleted = deleted;
}
```

}

My JSON HAL output:

```js
{
  "_embedded": {
    "commentList": [
      {
        "created": 1468176648000,
        "comment": "some comment",
        "senderId": 1,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/comments/11"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "created": 1468176649000,
        "comment": "some comment",
        "senderId": 1,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/comments/12"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "created": 1468176650000,
        "comment": "some comment",
        "senderId": 1,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/comments/13"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "created": 1468176650000,
        "comment": "some comment",
        "senderId": 1,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/comments/14"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "created": 1468176651000,
        "comment": "some comment",
        "senderId": 1,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/comments/15"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "created": 1468176651000,
        "comment": "some comment",
        "senderId": 1,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/comments/16"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "created": 1468176678000,
        "comment": "some comment",
        "senderId": 1,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/comments/17"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "created": 1468176679000,
        "comment": "some comment",
        "senderId": 1,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/comments/18"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "created": 1468176679000,
        "comment": "some comment",
        "senderId": 1,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/comments/19"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "created": 1468176680000,
        "comment": "some comment",
        "senderId": 1,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/comments/20"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8090/comments?user-id=1"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 1,
    "totalElements": 4,
    "totalPages": 5,
    "number": 38
  }
}
```

Seems to work, but no navigation links. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to implement the UI yourself.  Here is a pretty good tutorial: http://springinpractice.com/2012/05/11/pagination-and-sorting-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: are you sure? Even with spring boot? Every tutorial available shows that using PagingAndSortingRepository instead of a CrudRepository, returning a Page not List, should add them automatically. Ive got a fairly good idea how i would have done this manually, but documentation suggests i dont need to. Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: You didn't say you were using spring boot :)

Comment: I did lol, but no worries :P

Comment: You did!  Nothing leads me to believe that sprint boot by itself is going to give you a UI layer that knows how to page.

Comment: just one example of this is at header 6.1 in http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: That is when using Spring Data REST, you aren't using Spring Data Rest you are creating responses yourself.

Comment: please could you explain why you think im not using spring data rest. do you mean because i have a controller layer rather than annotating the repository with the path??

Answer (score 0):

The links are added by `PagedResourcesAssembler` which you need to use to create the `PagedResources` manually in the first place.

If you're using Spring Data REST, you don't need any of the controller code at all and can let Spring Data REST create the resources for you. See this [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) for a sample.

Comment: ok thanks. this was the impression i got.....that spring data rest doesnt need the controller,  however i MUST use a controller in my project for many reasons including 1) validation/verification eg i am wanting to comment on this post,  but first check if im actually the author of the post OR am friends with the author, otherwise i cant do it.  2) scenarios where i need ti use multiple dao/repository calls after an endpoint is hit. 
is there some way i can have a controller but still get the functionality? i never found a complex enough example

Comment: i am presuming many other people would have had this same need...to not just return data just because a user is logged in, but to process that data, pehaps combine it with data from other sources etc

Comment: I suppose I could rephrase this as "If i use spring-data-rest (which seems good and id love to do it), where would my program LOGIC go"?

Comment: Okay, i have found someone asking about the same problem. A good solution seems to be to use an aspect for the logic and annotate the repository with it.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place for discussion, but answering questions. Feel free to check out our [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-data).

Comment: Did you find a solution till now @apostrophedottilde? I have actually the same problem, that i need a controller, because its more complex than in the simple starter guides and the "default" save method. Can i get the links from my PagingAndSortingRepository in my controller? Or if i don't use a controller, where i have to place the business logic from the controller for a overriding save method with Spring Data REST? There is just the interface in the @RepositoryRestResource?